# Как я могу объединить два аудио в один, используя длину первого аудио?

Tags: linux, ffmpeg

Есть два аудио. Мне нужно соединить их между собой (два канала), но такой же длины, как и первый. Я нашел команду в Stack Overflow, которая частично решает мою проблему: `ffmpeg -i AgAD3RMAAvgr.ogg -i audio.mp3 -filter_complex amix=inputs=2:duration=longest output.mp3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

документация по фильтру http://underpop.online.fr/f/ffmpeg/help/amix.htm.gz

```
duration=first
```

-- Использовать длинну первого